# Why isn't C respecting my unsigned declaration?

Tags: c

Total C newbie here. When I run the following code:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int unsigned x = 1;
  printf("%d\n", x);
  x = x - 2;
  printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

I get the output:

> ```
> 1
> -1
> ```

i.e. signed output.

The compilation command was `cc -Wall -g -fno-stack-protector    exCurrent.c   -o exCurrent` and I ran this on a recent macOS 10.14.

What's happening?

Comment: printf doesn't know about the type of the passed arguments. It deduces them from the format string.

Comment: Try passing `%u`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf` doesn't know anything about the type of the variable you are passing to it. It simply sees its bits and then tries to represent that bit pattern based on the formatter (`%d` here).

As you can see, the bit patterns of signed and unsigned integers are exactly the same:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  unsigned int x = -1;
  int y = -1;
  printf("%X\n", x);
  printf("%X\n", y);
}
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> FFFFFFFF
> FFFFFFFF
> ```

You can use the `%u` formatter to see the unsigned int representation for the variable:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  unsigned int x = 1;
  printf("%u\n", x);
  x = x - 2;
  printf("%u\n", x);
}
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> 1
> 4294967295
> ```

Comment: "Sees its bits and then tries to represent that bit pattern based on the formatter " - paradigm shift! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

C respected your unsigned operator.

The problem is that `printf` just recieves the operands without and thinks that it is a signed int because of the `%d`.

This means, you should not use `%d` but the format string for unsigned integers, `%u` instead.

While substracting `2` from 1, you would get `-1` as a signed integer. The unsigned  equivalent is the highest unsigned integer possible(depending on your system, e.g. 2^32-1 if it is an 32-Bit integer)

So, if you use `%u` instead of `%d`, you'd get a (the highest possible if you don't consider `long`) integer result.

Answer (score 1):

Check format specifiers in c. Its a `%u` for unsigned integers.